# Sealed whey protein container past its use by date - is it still usable?

Tags: spoilage

I've had an accident that made me stop training for quite some time and I ended up with a sealed - never used nor opened - whey protein pot that expired Oct/2015.

Considering it's a powder and the package was closed and sealed, I opened and it still seems fine, with the same texture and smell as expected. I tried it and the flavour is very good as well.

What issues I could have using it? Would the proteins be "gone"? Could I have health problems?

Comment: So... really you don't know if it's spoiled or not... I think you need a title change.

Comment: When you say "sealed" do you mean "factory sealed" or do you mean that you'd used some of it but that you closed the tub tightly?

Comment: thanks for the fix, Catija! :) It is factory sealed, was never opened until today.

Comment: I've never tried whey powder, so this is not specific to your product, but some companies have that information available on their website, or by calling or e-mailing customer service. In the United States, I've done it with canned soup, yogurt, rice, and various other foods, and found it a helpful way to learn exactly what that date means.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You didn't say where your product was packaged, but according to the USDA, "Use by" dates refer to best quality, and are not safety dates.  This is especially true when foods are handled well...in your case, factory sealed.  Additionally, I can't see how the proteins would go anywhere.  Given the reportedly good flavor (not an indication of safety, but simply of good taste), I would use it.